# How to call Context layout inflater to another activity in android

Tags: android

In this activity , there is a `showCustomAlert` method. This method want to call in another activity.

```
    public void showCustomAlert(Context context , int message ) {
       try {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));

        TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);

        text.setText(message);

        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();

    } catch ( Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

This is my another activity here i want to call showCustomAlert method. I am getting an error null pointer exception.

```
Toss toast = new Toss();
toast.showCustomAlert(this , R.string.error_toast);
```

Comment: Post full *Logcat*.

Comment: post stack tarces

Comment: can you please post custom_toast and custom_toast_layout XML?

Answer (score 0):

**I guess the problem is in your `showCustomAlert()` method.**

**1.** When inflating `custom_layout`, use `ViewGroup` as `null` instead of `(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout)`.

```
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
```

**2.** When creating instance of `Toast`, use received `context` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

```
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
```

**Update your `Toss.java` class as below:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Toss {

    public void showCustomAlert(Context context , int message ) {

        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);
            text.setText(message);

            Toast toast = new Toast(context);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();

        } catch ( Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is a sample `custom_toast.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textToShow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**USE:**

```
Toss toast = new Toss();
toast.showCustomAlert(this , R.string.error_toast);
```

Here, `R.string.error_toast` contains text `This is a custom error toast`.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~